# Show a certain image if page h1 contains certain word?

Tags: jquery, css, image, show, contains

I'm trying to show an image which relates to the h1 containing a certain word. So let's say I have 20 pages and 20 images, and each page has a h1 which contains a word relating to the content. I'd like to be able to only show the image which relates to that word in the h1 on that page. This is what I was using (and I'm terrible at this!) to try to get it to show a picture of a ball.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($("h1:contains('ball')").length) {
      $('.post_image').show(<a href="#"><img src="ball.jpg" /></a>);
   }                                           
});
```

I'm guessing that's all kinds of wrong as it shows nothing. I need it to not only find and show that word and image, but at least 20 different.

Thanks in advance, much appreciated.

Comment: Do a simple string.search("ball") instead.

Comment: I think you'll have to post the HTML and some more explanation as to how this would work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Stilly.stack that you should approach this in a different way.

If you really want to check if the h1 contains a word, you could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var ballSrc = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Basketball.png';
   if ($("h1").text().indexOf('ball') !== -1) {
      $('.post_image').attr('src',ballSrc);
   }                                           
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aY5Nz/1/

**Edit:** This will also match words like "ballerina" so you should use a regex instead

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work well, but how would I load it up with different images relating to different words?

Comment: Just add as many if() clauses as you need. You also dont need to define ballSrc, but just place the url right into your if clause, e.g.
$('.post_image').attr('src', 'http://www.myserver.com/myimage.jpg');

Comment: Thanks! One very last thing - is there a way to add multiple indexof searches on one line? Only it appears case sensitive, so ('ball') and ('Ball') would be needed.

Comment: Yes you can add several conditions. For example
if($("h1").text().indexOf('ball') != -1 || $("h1").text().indexOf('Ball') != -1) { ...

More elegant would be to use Regular Expressions like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/aY5Nz/2/

Comment: Yeah, but regular expressions look massively confusing, haha! Thanks for all your help, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong way. You shouldn't have to check each word it may be. You can grab the word with the first line below. Make it into a url, and then just give it the source.

Note: Haven't tested it, but you could do what you want with very few lines of code like below.

```
    var theWord = $('h1').text();
    var theUrl = theWord + '.jpg';
    $('.post_image').attr('src', theUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a little confused about this one though. Could you explain it a little more please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($("h1:contains(ball)")) {
      $('.post_image').show('<a href="#"><img src="ball.jpg" alt="ball" /></a>');
   }                                           
});
```